# How to add values in awk

Tags: awk, sh

I have file which has log size like,

```
10.80 kb
60.08 kb
35.40 kb 
2.20 MB
1.10 MB
40.80 kb
3.15 MB
20.50 kb
```

I want to add awk one liner in such a way that it satisfy below conditions,

1. Convert kb to MB (divide by 1000)
2. get total in MB

I have written below awk code but it fails to add MB,

```
awk '{FS=" "} if ($2 ~ 'kb'){total += ($1/1000)}END{print total}'
```

This will convert kb's into MB and provide total but it does not add MB values to it. Please suggest?

Comment: Note: `$2=='kb'` should be `$2=="kb"`

Comment: Are you sure about your multiplication? By convention, "b" = byte, "B" = byte, but it's also unclear whether you know about [binary multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebibyte) and are using kilo/mega for 1000 on purpose or by accident when you might actually mean kibi/mebi for 1024.

Comment: It is kB and MB

Comment: 0. kb should be kB and 1. _convert kB to MB_ is kB divided by 1024, not by 1000.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
$ awk '{if ($2=="kb") total+=$1/1000; else total+=$1} END{print total}' file
6.61758
```

### How it works

For each line, the `if` statement is executed:

```
if ($2=="kb") total+=$1/1000; else total+=$1
```

If the second field is `kb`, then the total is increased by the first field divided by 1,000.  Otherwise, it is is increased by the first field.

After the code has finished reading the file, the total is printed.

#### Multi-line version

For those who prefer their code spread over multiple lines:

```
awk '
    {
        if ($2=="kb") 
           total+=$1/1000
        else
           total+=$1
     }

     END{
         print total
     }' file
```

Comment: Answer should be around 6.50 MB. Not 174.03, since addition of MB's is 2.20 + 1.10 + 3.15 + converted kb's (0.0020)

Comment: `$2=='kb'` should be `$2=="kb"`

Comment: Rock and @klashxx Thanks for catching that!  Answer updated.

Answer (score 4):

Using *ternary* operator:

```
$ awk '{total+= $1 / ($2=="kb" ? 1000: 1)}END{print total}' file
6.61758
```

**Explanation**

The operator *syntax*:

`expr ? action1 : action2`

In this example:

```
$2=="kb" ? 1000: 1
```

Depending of second field value (`expr`), our program will perform a different action, in this case its returning the numerical value of `1000` (`action1`) or just `1` (`action2`).

At this point `total` variable is used for accumulate `$1` value divided by the result given by the *ternary* operator.

```
total+= $1 / ($2=="kb" ? 1000: 1)
```

Check [this](https://klashxx.github.io/ternary-operator).

Comment: How does this work. Can you please elaborate,
{total+= $2=="kb" ? $1/1000: $1}

Comment: For catching the `'kb'` issue: +1.

Comment: @Rock, google ternary operator to find the likes of `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:`. I couldn't use a hyperlink as the SO editor cuts off the ending `:`! Note that an unpaerentheiszed ternary expression will cause syntax errors in some awks in some situations. I'd use `total+= ($2=="kb" ? $1/1000: $1)` or even better `total+= $1 / ($2=="kb" ? 1000: 1)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

"kb" (really kB) to MB conversion is kB divided by 1024. In the following kb and kB assumed as kB:

```
$ awk '$2 ~ /k[bB]/ {$1/=1024} {sum+=$1} END {print "sum:" sum}' foo
sum:6.61365
```

Comment: That should be true. It was true until the marketing people (who think larger numbers make for an easier sale) became involved.  Now, `kiB = 1024 B` and `kB = 1000 B`.  As @ghoti pointed out, this is documented [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebibyte).

Comment: Well, long live SI. It's heaven and hell. So have i typeth on min typewriterth.

Comment: For standing up for honesty and tradition: +1.